# Getting SamlSsoConfig Object Data through REST API

Tags: rest-api, saml

I'm trying to get SAML url of a particular user via REST API. But I can't find the SamlSsoConfig Object in the list of sobjects returned. I'm wondering if the Object is not exposed. Is there a way I can get the data?

Answer (score 1):

`SamlSsoConfig` is supported via the Metadata API, not the REST API. See [the entry for SamlSsoConfig in the Metadata API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#CSHID=meta_samlssoconfig.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/meta_samlssoconfig.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. I tried accessing the object with Metadata API but I got an error saying "The object not available for your organization". Could you explain me why this error came? 
I also tried calling the describeMetadata() method. This returned all the metadata types available. This too didn't have the SamlSsoConfig Object in it. Why is this happening?